# How to place icon in navigation bar

Tags: html, css

Hi I have created a navigation bar and I want to place a home image icon at the start of the navigation. However when I try to it either moves the other items down or when I hover over the icon the hover doesn't work properly.

```
<div id="nav">
    <div id="nav_wrapper">
      <ul>
         <li class="icon-home"><a href="#"></a></li>

            <li id="et"> <a href="#">England</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="Premiership.html">Premiership</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href= "#">Championship</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">League 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">League 2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="et"> <a href="#">France</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Ligue 1</a> 
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="et"> <a href="#">Germany </a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Bundesliga</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="et"> <a href="#">Italy</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Serie A</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="et"> <a href="#">Spain</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">La Liga</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>    

    </div>
    <!-- Nav wrapper end -->

  </div>
```

In the link below I managed to get the heading in line however the hover effect doesn't work.  http://jsfiddle.net/mxohL7kL/

Comment: Here is some trying if it will help you: http://jsfiddle.net/jani11bolkvadze/mxohL7kL/7/ No time to continue.. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The home link has no text in it, that is why your hover effect is not the same height as the other link. What you could do is, gives the home anchor a text and hide it.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<li class="icon-home"><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>

//css
.icon-home a span {
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

[see the example here](http://jsfiddle.net/mxohL7kL/6/)

Comment: Thanks for your help just one slight problem it work but when I hover over the house the background goes black like I ain't selecting it.

Comment: I moved the icon to link `.icon-home a:before ` http://jsfiddle.net/mxohL7kL/8/ Also please note this is might solve your original problem but I haven't tested it in other browser.